# querying a specific result set

Tags: mysql, sql

In this workorder table there are multiple workorder elements.  Each element is either a parent where in the parent column it is null or a child. The child will contain the parents wonum.  What I am looking to achieve is have a query that will select a parent if the status is COMP.  If a parent elements status is COMP then retrieve also the children associated with that parent element.  The biggest problem I am having is getting the appropriate children.  If a parent does not have a status COMP then do not include the children in the result set regardless of the children status.

**Workorder Table**

```
wonum     parent     status     worktype  
=====     ======     ======     ========
1000      NULL       COMP       INSP
1002      1000       COMP       INSP
1005      1000       COMP       INSP
1006      NULL       APPR       INSP
1008      1006       COMP       INSP
1009      1006       COMP       INSP
1010      1006       APPR       INSP
1011      1006       COMP       INSP
```

**Desired Output**

```
wonum     parent     status     worktype
=====     ======     ======     ========
1000      NULL       COMP       INSP
1002      1000       COMP       INSP
1005      1000       COMP       INSP
```

By this small sample data.  I have two parents ( 1000 and 1006).  1006  still has children elements with the status of APPR.  I would like to query the parent and the children associated to that parent. All with the status COMP.

Comment: Does this go deeper than two levels (ie more than parent + child)? Will there ever be a wonum with a parent with a value of 1002?

Comment: It will always be a parent child relationship. So it will at most go down two levels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm surprised this wasn't answered much earlier.  From what it sounds, I would do a pre-query of all work orders where the parent is null and status is "COMP".  From that, you have the top-most work order.  Then grab all children of that work order

```
select
      yt2.*
   from
      ( select yt.wonum
           from YourTable yt
           where parent is null
             and status = 'COMP' ) PQ
      JOIN YourTable yt2
         on PQ.wonum = yt2.wonum
         OR PQ.wonum = yt2.parent
   order by
      coalesce( yt2.parent, yt2.wonum ),
      case when yt2.parent is null
           then 1 else 2 end
```

So, the inner pre-query is going to capture your work order 1000 as the top-level parent is null and status is 'COMP'.  Next join that directly back to your table again based on the prequalified work order number for EITHER the work order number OR the parent matching.  This will give you all the rows for any qualified completed work order.

Now, to keep the related work orders together we have the order by.  The first part of the order by use a COALESCE() which says... if the first parameter is null, use the second.  So, for the "parent" record of null, it will grab the work order value of 1000.  For the child entries that DO have a parent value, it will grab their 1000 parent values.  So now you have all respective work orders together per respective parent.

Finally, the SECOND part of the order by.  I'm doing a case/when here.  If the parent ID value is null, then this is the first entry for the entire order.  Put IT in first position, then anything else after that.

For help optimizing the query, ensure your table has an index on
(parent, status)
and an additional index on (wonum, parent)

Comment: Yes, it's simple. But it was unclear if it was a hierarchy of unknown depth, or a simple parent-child relationship.

Comment: This was well explained. Thank you. One more question I am just looking into seeing if this would work on an Oracle and DB2 database as well. I don't see it running into conflicts atleast for Oracle.

Comment: @DerekParker, I would not expect to see any issues in Oracle, but never worked DB2.